# Cursor based pagination in Mongo DB where skip or limit is not known

Tags: mongodb, go, pagination, graphql, cursor

I want to use cursor based pagination in Mongo DB. My cursor is an object id. When I run a find query with sort the final result is a list of documents that includes one with above mentioned cursor (object id).

What I want is to be able to get only those documents that are later in the result than given cursor. Which is different from using Skip because I can't know the index of the specific document in the result matching the cursor (object id).

Same goes for backward pagination which is to be able to get only those documents that are before in the result than given cursor.

This is a blocker in my case because of efficiency requirement as the result can be huge list of documents. So I can't just iterate over the result and skip documents before the cursor. I've already tried that and it fails miserably when user keeps scrolling to later part of the result.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

As a note, I'm using Go Mongo driver and gqlgen graphql server if it's relevant for your answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)‘s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too - despite its „harsh“ title.

Comment: The thing is that you need to sort on a specific field, otherwise the results will come in what is called „natural“ order, which basically means „undetermined“ for your purpose. For a scrolling frontend, I prolly would go for some sort of repository like React‘s Flux or Vue‘s Vuex, loading roughly 2 times the number of entries shown in each direction. Hard to make more detailed without seeing the actual code, problem and design ;)